# UIPageViewController does not show its view controllers views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController`  in a `UIViewController` , I am having a problem where the pageviewcontroller's inner view are not shown [Although I am sure they are loaded from the server]!

**Some helpful notes:**

`UIPageViewController` (called :*pageController*)

Outer `UIViewController` (called :*OfferDetailsViewController*)

each viewController inside the pageController is of type `OfferBannerPageViewController`

Here is my code related to the problem , *Please ask for any other blocks of code if you think it will help finding the problem source*

some of :**`OfferDetailsViewController.m`** :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    if(_offerId)
    {
        _offer = [[Offer alloc]init];
        [delegate setUpAConnectionToGetADetailedOffer:_offerId];
        //first: load the offer
        [self loadOffer];
        [self startTimer];
    }
}

-(void) loadOffer{
        NSMutableString * pathPattern = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"api/Offers/"];

        [pathPattern appendString:_offerId];

        [[RKObjectManager sharedManager]getObjectsAtPath:pathPattern parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
            if(mappingResult){
                _offer = (Offer *)[mappingResult.array firstObject];
                //second load the offer banners images
                [self setOfferView];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self loadOfferBanners];
                });

            }else{
            }
        }
        failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        }];
}

-(void)loadOfferBanners {

    _offer.OfferPannerImagesObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for(int index = 0 ; index<_offer.OfferPannerImages.count ;index++){
        NSURL *imageURL =[NSURL URLWithString:_offer.OfferPannerImages[index]];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        //[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        if(image){
            [_offer.OfferPannerImagesObjects addObject: image];
        }
    }
    if(_offer.OfferPannerImagesObjects.count>0){
        [self setUpOfferBanners];
    }
}

-(void)setUpOfferBanners {

self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc]initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

    self.pageController.dataSource = self;
    CGRect rect = [self.pagesView bounds];
    [[self.pageController view] setFrame:CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height)];

    OfferBannerPageViewController * initialBanner = [self viewControllerAtIndex: 0];
    [self.pageController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:initialBanner, nil] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil ];

    [self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
    [[self pagesView] addSubview:[self.pageController view]];
    [self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    self.pagesView.clipsToBounds=YES;
    self.pagesView.layer.cornerRadius= 6;
}
```

here is the ViewControllerAtIndex method **I debug it and found that index is always  whereas when I hover in it after stopping at a break point I see its value as 0!**

```
- (OfferBannerPageViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    OfferBannerPageViewController *offerBannerPageViewController = [[OfferBannerPageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OfferBannerPageViewController" bundle:nil];

    offerBannerPageViewController.bannerView = _offer.OfferPannerImagesObjects[index];

    offerBannerPageViewController.index = [NSNumber numberWithLong:(long)index];
    NSLog(@"____________________ [INDEX = %ld] ___________________",(long)index);

    [offerBannerPageViewController.bannerView setImage:_offer.OfferPannerImagesObjects[index]];

    return offerBannerPageViewController;
}
```

any help will be extremely appreciated, Thank you.

**update**

```
- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController: (UIPageViewController*)pageViewController {
    // The number of items reflected in the page indicator.
    return [_offer.OfferPannerImages count];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
    // The selected item reflected in the page indicator.
    return 0;
}

-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{

    NSInteger index = (long)((OfferBannerPageViewController *)viewController).index;
    if(index >= _offer.OfferPannerImagesObjects.count){
        return nil;
    }
    index ++;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSInteger index = (long)((OfferBannerPageViewController *)viewController).index;
    if(index == 0)
        return nil;
    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}
```

**update 2: OfferBannerPageViewController.h**

```
@interface OfferBannerPageViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSNumber * index;
@property (strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView * bannerView;
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented `presentationCountForPageViewController`, `presentationIndexForPageViewController`, `viewControllerBeforeViewController` *and* `viewControllerAfterViewController` methods?
Please, show them.

Comment: I believe that when you get the index, you should use “pageIndex” instead of “index”
NSInteger index =((OfferBannerPageViewController *)viewController).pageIndex;

Comment: thank you for your effort, I am not sure about that as I don't have pageIndex property in OfferBannerPageViewController class

Comment: Ah, right. Take a look at an example, I hope you will find what is wrong with your code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ik34ydd675lu67/PageViewDemo.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this, but maybe you should use autoresizing masks to make sure OfferBannerPageViewController's view resizes width and height along with the superview. It might happen that when you set the frame of pageController.view based on bounds of superview, the bounds are 0 width and height and then doesn't resize.

So try:

```
[[self.pageController view] setFrame:CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height)];
[[self.pageController view] setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```